# tox throws and error when running nosetest command

Tags: python, python-3.x, nose, setup.py, tox

I created this `tox.ini` file:

```
[tox]
envlist = py37

[testenv]
commands = /bin/sh nosetests config_test.test_config_sdk:test_bucket_existing
```

It throws this error:

```
$ tox
GLOB sdist-make: /Users/me/git/config-test/setup.py
py37 create: /Users/me/git/config-test/.tox/py37
py37 inst: /Users/me/git/config-test/.tox/.tmp/package/1/sdk-config-1.0.0.zip
py37 installed: sdk-config==1.0.0,config-test==1.0.0
py37 run-test-pre: PYTHONHASHSEED='2567467531'
py37 runtests: commands[0] | /bin/sh nosetests config_test.test_config_sdk:test_bucket_existing
/Users/me/git/config-test/venv/bin/nosetests: line 3: import: command not found
/Users/me/git/config-test/venv/bin/nosetests: line 4: import: command not found
from: can't read /var/mail/nose
/Users/me/git/config-test/venv/bin/nosetests: nosetests: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/Users/me/git/config-test/venv/bin/nosetests: nosetests: line 9: `    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])'
ERROR: InvocationError for command '/bin/sh nosetests config_test.test_config_sdk:test_bucket_existing' (exited with code 2)
__________________________________________________________________________ summary ___________________________________________________________________________
ERROR:   py37: commands failed
```

`nosetests config_test.test_config_sdk:test_bucket_existing` works when I run it in my terminal though.

Have I done something wrong or is this command not possible in tox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the command you have registered for `tox` to run:

```
/bin/sh nosetests config_test.test_config_sdk:test_bucket_existing
```

Here, `nosetests` is invoked as a shell script; but that's misleading.

`nosetests` is an executable python script in your `PATH` and should be executed directly.

Registering the command as:

```
nosetests config_test.test_config_sdk:test_bucket_existing
```

solves the error.